# Spring Tool Suite not possible to create new project with Gradle: Can not import using Gradle (STS) because STS Gradle Tooling is not installed

Tags: gradle, spring-tool-suite, gradle-eclipse, buildship

I'm using the Spring Tool Suite:

Version: 3.9.0.RELEASE
Build Id: 201707061903
Platform: Eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3)

And the Gradle plugin installed:

Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle  2.1.1.v20170713-0942    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship

I'm trying to create a new Spring Starter Project, but I've this message when I select the type "Gradle (Buildship 1.x)" or "Gradle (Buildship 2.x)" or "Gradle (STS)"

> Can not import using Gradle (Buildship 2.x) because Buildship Gradle
>   Tooling version 2.x is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse
>   Marketplace.

Any help?

Thanks, Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buildship 2.1.2 got released (available from the Eclipse Marketplace) and is fully compatible with STS 3.9.0 again.

Answer (score 1):

Buildship 2.1.0 and 2.1.1 is not compatible with STS 3.9.0, more details can be found here:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-ide/issues/163

The solution is to install Buildship 2.0.x from the Eclipse Oxygen update site instead.