# Spring Tool Suite (STS-3.9.1) not possible to create new project/import existing project with Gradle

Tags: spring-boot

When I select Build Type as "Gradle (Buildship 2.x)", following error is thrown:
 *Can not import using Gradle (Buildship 2.x) because Buildship Gradle Tooling version 2.x is not installed. You can install it from Eclipse*

Similar errors are thrown for other Gradle build options.

With File -> Import, Gradle is not listed in the import wizards.

Am using eclipse-SDK-4.7.1a, and have already installed *Buildship: Eclipse plug-ins for Gradle: 2.2.0*.

[Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45376675/spring-tool-suite-not-possible-to-create-new-project-with-gradle-can-not-import) says, Buildship 2.1.2 is compatible. But am still unable to leverage Gradle build with STS 3.9.1 with Buildship 2.2.0.

Restarted and retried multiple times, but no luck!